# How to add custom 'project item nodes' to Visual Studio Flavoured Project

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have written a simple flavoured project for Visual Studio 2008, and I want to add a custom 'folder' item to the solution explorer, similar to the 'references' folder.
This folder will contain more 'custom' nodes, which dont actually represent files, but in-memory objects.
How do I hook into what is displayed in the solution explorer?
I cant seem to find any simple code examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should edit your .vcproj file. Google Mock does this to have a fake "Public header files" and a "Private header files" filter.

http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/source/browse/trunk/msvc/gmock.vcproj#199